# What sort of analysis should be done in order to define our target outcome for modelling customer lapse?

Tags: predictive-modeling, churn

I am trying to build a model to predict customer lapse and am required to define the target lapse definition myself.

What sort of customer behavioural analysis should I do in order to define my modelling target? In other words, what sort of analysis could help me decide between a lapse definition of 90 days without a purchase compared to 180 days.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to do the analysis in a scripting language, you can define `days_since_last_purchase` as a variable. Then you can systematically change the variable to see which value makes the most sense.

There are a couple of options:

- Look for an inflection point in the performance.
- Show the results to a domain expert to choose a target value.
- Use a distribution of possible target values instead of a single point estimate, aka a Bayesian perspective.